# Freeing up audio device

Tags: sound, hardware

I am trying to run an executable that plays a sound with the portaudio library.

when I compile and run the filesystem I get the following error.

> Error number: -9985 Error message: Device unavailable

I am wondering how to free up the audio device and run the executable and return the audio device back to the way it was so I can use it with the system.

Answer (score 1):

Under Ubuntu, the pulseaudio daemon 'hogs' the audio devices. Instead of killing it, you can make it swallow your application's OSS output like this:
`padsp ./yourApp`

If that doesn't work, here's a link bug report on how the fedora guys overcame a similar problem with audacity:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=445644